# How do get summation of return values in different time python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import sentiment as vaderSentiment

count=0;

f1 = open('testData.txt')#input file 

sentence= f1.readline()

while sentence:

    count += 1

    print (sentence)

    vs =vaderSentiment(sentence)

    print ("\t" + str(vs))

    sentence=f1.readline()

f1.close
```

This is the code.There input file has many sentences in lines.And result is like this.

ex:
she is good

```
{'pos': 0.592, 'neu': 0.408, 'neg': 0.0, 'compound': 0.4404}
```

she is well

```
{'pos': 0.512, 'neu': 0.488, 'neg': 0.0, 'compound': 0.2732}
```

I want to get whole text file positive ,negative,neutral seprately.That mean as an example  summation of positive counts of sentences.so plz help me .I dont know what to do

Comment: i want like this      ex:   'text file pos is : xxxx'  like that, xxxx is a num,after i get this i can do other things,plz any expert in python help me.i want a reply immediately

Comment: Its not very clear to me what you are looking after, but as far as i understood, you want to process the dictionary result . You already has the counter so the line will be apparent, you can easily get the values by calling their key names. like vs['neu'] which in first example results in 0.408.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, hope it helps

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import sentiment as vaderSentiment

testData = ['VADER is smart, handsome, and funny.', 'VADER is smart, handsome, and funny!', 'VADER is very smart, handsome, and funny.', 'VADER is VERY SMART, handsome, and    FUNNY.', 'VADER is VERY SMART, handsome, and FUNNY!!!', 'VADER is VERY SMART, really handsome, and INCREDIBLY FUNNY!!!', 'The book was good.', 'The book was kind of good.',    'The plot was good, but the characters are uncompelling and the dialog is not great.', 'A really bad, horrible book.', "At least it isn't a horrible book.", ':) and :D', '',   'Today sux', 'Today sux!', 'Today SUX!', "Today kinda sux! But I'll get by, lol"]

result = { 'pos':[] , 'neg':[], 'compound':[], 'neu':[] }

for item in testData:
    vs =vaderSentiment(item)
    result['pos'].append(vs['pos'])
    result['neg'].append(vs['neg'])
    result['compound'].append(vs['compound'])
    result['neu'].append(vs['neu'])

print 'sum:'
for i in result.keys():
    print '\t',i, '=>', sum(result[i])
```

sum:
    neg => 3.542
    neu => 5.59
    pos => 6.868
    compound => 4.7512

Comment: yh i want finally summation each sentiment one,I will try this and see.thank you very much for helping me

Comment: sum: neg => 3.542 neu => 5.59 pos => 6.868 compound => 4.7512                   after get this ,i want to cal pos of sum AND BREAK THE RANGE.HOW CAN I DO THIS?? plz help me

Comment: can you please explain more, i don't understand correctly . you wanto calculate the pos value and break the for loop ? can you show an example of desired output you looking for ?